# json and type casting

Tags: json, go

I am attempting to read a json file that looks like

```
 [{ "title": "hi", "tags": [1,2,3,4,5,6] }, {...}, {...}]
```

and the code looks like this

```
 contentdat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("content.json")
 check(err)
 var content []interface{}
 err = json.Unmarshal(contentdat, &content)
 check(err)


for i, contentItem := range content {
    vertedContentItem := contentItem.(map[string]interface{})
    contentTags := vertedContentItem["tags"].([]interface{})
    contentItemTags := make([]int, len(contentTags))
    for i, ctv := range contentTags {
        contentItemTags[i] = int(ctv.(float64))
    }
```

what I am trying to figure out is how I can avoid the doing all the type casting and just access the json obj directly or maybe just type cast once for the entire json structure. I had a idea about defining the structure of the internal object like so

```
type Content struct {
  title string
  tags []int
}
```

and then declare content as

```
var content []Content
```

instead of interface{} and just loop through the structure as expected but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: The sample JSON is invalid.

Comment: Duplicate. The 3'000ths.

Comment: We need to pick a canonical "export your fields" question/answer so we can easily close duplicates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must export the fields of the "Content" struct that you wish to de/serialize by using capital letters:

```
type Content struct {
  Title string
  Tags  []int
}
```

For example:

```
type Content struct {
  Title string
  Tags  []int
}

func main() {
  jsonstr := `[{"title":"hi","tags":[1,2,3,4,5,6]}]`
  contents := []Content{}

  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &contents)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Printf("%#v\n", contents)
  // => []main.Content{main.Content{Title:"hi", Tags:[]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did work. Why do I need to export the fields?

Comment: @MikeF because fields whose name starts with a lower-case letter are "private" (not available outside of the named package) and fields whose name starts with an upper-case letter are "exported" (i.e. public, available outside of the named package). The [JSON un/marshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) was designed to only consider _exported_ fields. See also this article about [JSON and Go](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go).